# Qual é a diferença entre diretivas (directive) e componentes (component)?

Tags: angularjs

Parece que em versões mais recentes, além do método `directive`, o Angular 1 conta também com um método chamado [`component`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Eu gostaria de entender as diferenças principais entre um e outro.

Qual são as principais diferenças entre um `directive` e um `component`?

Quando eu devo usar `component` ao invés de uma `directive`?

<sub>Antes que me questionem isso: A página da documentação está em inglês, gostaria de uma explicação em português, que para mim é mais fácil.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

O Component é uma Directive especial, ele foi criado para suprir e corrigir problemas que a directive possui quando voce quer criar um componente html que possui um controller e um html proprio, esses problemas seriam: nao possui bindings, nao possui scope isolado e ambiguidades geradas pelas especificações das directives do tipo link e atributo.

Voce deve usar um Component: Sempre que quiser criar um componente html de scopo isolado (substitui a criação de um html com binding via ng-controller de um controller).

Voce deve usar uma Directive: Apenas quando voce quiser criar um atributo que executa algum javascript de manipulação de DOM ou manipulação simples de informação.

Answer (score 0):

O componente é similar a diretiva, porem ela é mais fácil de configurar e vem com a tendencia de facilitar a migração dos projetos do Angular 1.x para o Angular 2. Porem os componentes são limitados apenas a atributos.